# Where are TFS Alerts stored in the TFS Databases? Receiving duplicate alerts after upgrade 2008 to 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I recently performed a migration-upgrade from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010.  Almost everything is working properly now.  However, our team is getting duplicate emails now.  I'm guessing this is because I used the TFS 2008 power tools to setup alerts.  After the upgrade, I installed the TFS 2010 power tools and noticed that there were not alerts configured.  I setup new alerts and now we get duplicates.  Is it possible the old alerts configuration is floating around in the db somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Event subscriptions are stored in the tbl_EventSubscription tables from the Tfs_Configuration database and the team project collection database however manually modifying the databases is not supported. Do you still have a client machine running Visual Studio 2008 with the TFS2008 Power Tools? If so, you could try to use the 2008 Alerts editor to remove the old subscriptions.

Ladislau

Comment: This answer was correct, but I had to connect to my Collection database (not tfs_configuration) to find the alerts.