# Sharing TSF 2010 Team Alerts

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

Is there a way to access another Admin's Team Alerts in TFS 2010?

I don't have much experience using TFS other than checking code in/out. I was recently put in charge of changing around some team alerts that were previously created by another Admin. Is there a way for me to access the alerts he set up?

There are over 100 alerts which will be a pain if I have to remake them on my account. If anyone knows of an easier way such as exporting the alerts or transferring them I would appreciate it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446758/edit-other-users-alerts-for-a-project-in-tfs

Comment: Isaiah4110,  Dan as beginner on TFS must access by interface easily, article don't treat explicitly this aspect

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Tfs Web Access, click on `Settings` at the `top right corner`, select `Team project\Alerts`

Other solution :

You can use the `BisSubscribe` tool commandline located on your tfs server in `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Tools`