# TFS Administrators getting TFS alerts for everything?

Tags: tfs, tfs-alerts

We have 3 TFS Administrators in our TFS 2012 environment. It seems that each administrator is getting TFS alerts for everything. Are TFS administrators supposed to get all alerts by default? Example 1 - We have Team alerts setup for team projects within TFS. The alerts are configured to alert someone when they are assigned a work item. That is working as expected. However, all 3 TFS administrators are also getting those alerts. Even if they aren't in the assigned to field. Example 2 - We have a TFS project where we do NOT have any Team Alerts setup for. All 3 TFS Administrators are receiving all alerts. The admins receive alerts when a test cases is linked to another, when a task is created, if anything changes with any work item. Has anyone experienced this or heard about this happening? I have looked everywhere but found nothing. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Did you check if the administrators are in the team group for which you have set up the team alerts? Sometimes the administrators are in these groups because of the group inheritance.

Comment: Yes we have checked that. The alerts are setup to notify someone of they are assigned a work item. All tfs admins are getting all alerts, even for the projects that have NO alerts setup

Answer (score 0):

You have an alert configured that has the Team Project removed from the filter. This results in an alert that exists in a single team project being applied to everyone.

If your open up the web access and go to the alerts administration page you should be able to list all of the alerts that are current configured and find the culprit.

Comment: There is not any alerts setup for one of the projects. All TFS admins are getting alerts that test cases are being linked to other test cases. There are no alerts setup to notify anyone if this happens. Not sure why the admins are getting alerts when no alert exists?

Comment: Check with : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446758/edit-other-users-alerts-for-a-project-in-tfs